# Discrete math: Is the survey accurate?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A library has conducted a survey of its readers. The survey asked its $10,000$ readers about their reading habits and the number of books that they have borrowed from the library in $2012$. It has found that its readers claimed to have borrowed $75,000$ books in $2012$. The library has also reviewed the borrowing records of its books and found that on average a book was borrowed $5$ times. The library has $20,000$ books.

Is this survey accurate?

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If you add up the numbers of times each of the $20,000$ books in the library was borrowed to get the total number of borrowings, and divide that by $20,000$, you get the average of $5$ borrowings per book. That tells you that the total number of borrowings must have been ... what? Does this agree with the number of borrowings reported by the library’s readers?